# Subscribing multiple topics with different rate

Tags: ros, messages, callback, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I´m currently new at ROS but made yet all the beginner tutorials at the ROS homepage.

First I implemented a simple publisher and subscriber and it worked. Now I want to create something like the following:

- Node A which publishes a string with rate(1) to topic “test_01” , variable var01
- Node B which publishes an int with rate(1) to topic “test_02”, variable var02
- Node C which publishes an int with rate(10) to topic “test_03” , variable var03

I want to have the following workflow: an node D which subscribes to all three nodes A-C and producing the following output on the screen:

**cout << “%s %i %i” << var01 var02 var03 << endl;**

So each time a message is published, the cout should performed with the actual variables.
As I understood so far, CallbackQueues (http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#CallbackQueue::callAvailable.28.29_and_callOne.28.29) might be the right strategy, but after hours of trying without success I don´t have any idea how to implement the workflow…

Happy about every hint

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315942/subscribing-multiple-topics-with-different-rate/) by [pse18_10](https://answers.ros.org/users/40087/pse18_10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems like something that would not require separate `CallbackQueue`s, but can be solved with "global variables" or [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) (more specifically: [Cache](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Cache).

If you want to keep it simple: in every callback, first store the incoming msg into a global variable (or any variable that exists in a scope other than the local callback/function scope), then print your log message. Do this for all callbacks.

Any time any of the callbacks receives a message, the log message will be printed with the "last" received value of the other subscriptions. You might want to see whether you'd have to lock any of the variables to avoid reading (printing) stale data, but that would be an optimisation (almost).

As to `Cache`: if your messages have a header: store each incoming msg in a `Cache`, lookup corresponding (or *latest* messages for the other subscriptions), then print the log message.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pse18_10](https://answers.ros.org/users/40087/pse18_10/) on 2019-02-20**:
I made it with global variables, thanks a lot!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-20**:
Good to hear you got it to work: now improve on it by not using global variables :)